# Azure Devops Pipelines - Add multiple/batch variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using the below `azure-pipeline.yml` file to build docker image, push to Azure docker registry & restart the Azure docker app servicer.

This yaml file uses variable set in azure pipeline, screenshot attached.

My issue is, I need to create 2-3 pipelines every-week for different projects I need to add every variable manually for each project and copy paste from my config. Is there a way I can import a .env file or add multiple variables all at once while creating the pipeline.

Objectively I need to cut down the single variable copy paste time & avoid errors that might occurr

[image]

Comment: Any reason you're not putting them in the YAML file's `variables` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You could use [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to reuse variables.

```
trigger: 
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- group: forTest

steps:
- script: |
    echo $(test1)
    echo $(test2)
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

[image]

2.You could use [variable template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse).

```
trigger: 
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- template: vars.yml

steps:

- script: |
    echo $(test1)
    echo $(test2)
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

[image]

Comment: Another good thing about this, is that if the variables are the same or name are the same, you can `clone` the **variable group** and just change the values accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jiawei, I use the same `.azure-piplines.yml` file to deploy multiple environments like staging/prod etc in multiple pipelines. Each environment has it's own variables defined in pipelines is there anyways I can use different values for different pipelines? Using the same yaml file

Comment: If you want to use the same azure-piplines.yml, you just need to modify the content of vars.yml for different projects. You could add multiple variables all at once.